# how using --use-ngrams in mallet

Tags: mallet

I want to run mallet using the --use-ngrams true option but can't seem to get it working.

```
bin\mallet import-file --input ovary.txt --output ovary2.mallet --keep-sequence-bigrams --remove-stopwords

bin\mallet train-topics --input ovary2.mallet --output-topic-keys ovary_keys2_2.txt --use-ngrams true --num-topics 15
```

But I'm getting this error:

> Unrecognized option 4: --use-ngrams

Comment: Which version of mallet are you using? The latest version does not support n-grams attribute. The n-grams attribute has been removed from the latest version. The present mallet version uses inbuilt n-grams feature before giving the output. So, either use the latest version or let me know the version which you are using.

Answer (score 1):

In mallet version 2.0.8 you would use:

```
bin\mallet import-file --input ovary.txt --output ovary2.mallet --keep-sequence-bigrams --remove-stopwords   --gram-sizes 1,2

bin\mallet train-topics --input ovary2.mallet --output-topic-keys ovary_keys2_2.txt  --num-topics 15
```

You an see the available options at:

```
bin\mallet import-file  --help

bin\mallet train-topics --help
```